# Under what conditions principal directions define an integrable distribution?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, hypersurfaces

Consider a hypersurface $M^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ which is compact without boundary. Assume that its second fundamental form $A$ has distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1<\ldots<\lambda_k$ (with $k$ constant on $M$), and that the eigenspace $E_i$ associated to each $\lambda_i$ has constant dimension $\dim(E_i) = m_i$ on $M$.

Is it true that each $E_i$ defines an involutive distribution on $M$ ? Involutive in the sense that for any vector field $x,y\in E_i$, it holds $[x,y]\in E_i$ ?

If it is not true, is there some assumption to guarantee this ? If it is true, then we should be able to decompose $M$ as a product of $k$ manifolds, each of them having dimension $m_i$, no ?